# Boxes with text or numbers

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, boxes, underbrace, overbrace

I am trying to get a neater version of something like this[image: What I want to get]

Following is what I have done to get this

```
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
     \overbrace{\fbox{r}\fbox{r+1}\dots\fbox{2r-1}}_{Block-2}\ \ \ \ &\underbrace{\fbox{2r}\dots\fbox{r+k-1}\fbox{0}\dots\fbox{r-1}}_{Block-3}\ \ \ \ \overbrace{\fbox{r+k}\dots\fbox{k+2r-1}}_{Block-4}\\
       & \hspace{1ex}\Big\downarrow\\
    \underbrace{\fbox{2r}\dots\fbox{r+k-1}\fbox{0}\dots\fbox{r-1}}_{Block-3}\ \ \ \ 
       & \overbrace{\fbox{r+k}\dots\fbox{k+2r-1}}_{Block-4} \ \ \ \ 
    \overbrace{\fbox{r}\dots\fbox{k+r-1}}_{Block-2}
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}
```

Some boxes are of different sizes. I want the arrow to be in the middle, and also the lower part under the arrow to be aligned with upper part.

I am also trying to get the following, but couldn't figure out how to start doing it

[image: No clue]

The text can be in black. I just drew the picture to show what I want to get.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can define your own box with the height of a `k` and the depth of a `j` by using `\vphantom{$jk$}` in the definition. You can change which blocks have `\overbrace` and `\underbrace` if you like.

Then put the three lines into an `array` with `\Big\downarrow` in the second row. You can use a different size if you like, e.g., `\big` or `\bigg`. Spacing is adjusted with `\arraystretch{2.5}`. You can adjust the spacing by changing the `2.5`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\framebox{$#1$\vphantom{$jk$}}}

\begin{document}
\[\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{array}{c}
\overbrace{\mybox{r}\mybox{r+1}\cdots\mybox{2r-1}}^{\textup{Block }-2}\qquad
    \overbrace{\mybox{2r}\cdots\mybox{r+k-1}\mybox{0}\cdots\mybox{r-1}}^{\textup{Block }-3}\qquad
    \overbrace{\mybox{r+k}\cdots\mybox{k+2r-1}}^{\textup{Block }-4}\\
\Big\downarrow\\
\underbrace{\mybox{2r}\cdots\mybox{r+k-1}\mybox{0}\cdots\mybox{r-1}}_{\textup{Block }-3}\qquad
    \underbrace{\mybox{r+k}\cdots\mybox{k+2r-1}}_{\textup{Block }-4}\qquad
    \underbrace{\mybox{r}\mybox{r+1}\cdots\mybox{2r-1}}_{\textup{Block }-2}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Can you help with second part of the question ?  how a empty box can be created ?

Comment: @Sergio: I'm not sure where the empty boxes are supposed to go, but you could use `\mybox{\hspace{5mm}}` to create a box with the same height and whatever width you want.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to create your first diagram or drawing:

[image: result]

I use `tikz`, its `shapes.multipart` library for `split rectangles`, and `positioning` for relative placement. Please find details in the pfg manual.

Basically you still place `\node` statements, in relative postion (right of, below), with `{text}` still inside braces. By intention I didn't create the most compact code version possible, so you can still follow the details of development.

After having placed all 6 nodes, I moved the common `style` options, calling it `reg`, right after the `\tikz` statement. This style is included in each node AND details for `split` and `labels` are given there. By using the ignore functionality these parts could have been written more compact. Left this way, simply the number of `parts` and the nodes `labels` do vary from node to node.

Finally I `draw` an arrow from node (b) to(d), which happen to be the thingies in the middle of both rows: it's possible to retreat start and end a little. It's also possible to change the tip of the arrow, if needed. To my taste the braces aren't necessary: they don't add more relevant information, do they?

Please find relevant new thoughts in the comments after each line.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, positioning}

\begin{document}


    \tikz [reg/.style={draw=black!60, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal}]{
        % --- 1st row --------------------
        \node  [reg,% <<< common style, see above 
                rectangle split parts=4,% <<< 4 split rectangles 
                label=$Block-2$] (a)    {% <<< label above, naming this node (a)
            $r$
            \nodepart{two} $r+1$
            \nodepart{three} $...$
            \nodepart{four} $2r-1$
        };
        
        \node [reg, rectangle split parts=6, 
               right=of a,% <<< positioning it somehow right of node (a)
               label=$Block-3$] (b)     {
            $2r$
            \nodepart{two} $...$
            \nodepart{three} $r+k-1$
            \nodepart{four} $0$
            \nodepart{five} $...$
            \nodepart{six} $r-1$
        };

        \node [reg, rectangle split parts=3, right=of b, label=$Block-4$] (c)   {
            $r+k$
            \nodepart{two} $...$
            \nodepart{three} $k+2r-1$
        };
        
        % --- 2nd row --------------------
        \node [reg, rectangle split parts=6, 
               below=of a,% <<< put below node (a)
               label=below:$Block-3$] (f)   {% put nodes label below of this thingie
            $2r$
            \nodepart{two} $...$
            \nodepart{three} $r+k-1$
            \nodepart{four} $0$
            \nodepart{five} $...$
            \nodepart{six} $r-1$
        };

        \node [reg, rectangle split parts=3, below=of b, label=below:$Block-4$] (d)     {
            $r+k$
            \nodepart{two} $...$
            \nodepart{three} $k+2r-1$
        };

        \node [reg, rectangle split parts=3, below=of c, label=below:$Block-2$] (e)     {
            $r$
            \nodepart{two} $...$
            \nodepart{three} $k+r-1$
        };

      % --- connecting both middle thingies ---------
      \draw [->] (b) -- (d);% "draw -> from node (b) to node (d)"       
    }
 
\end{document}
```